# public key not working for a new laptop to connect to github

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to add a new ssh key for my new laptop, but after adding it, it is always rejected for the public key issue, anyone have any ideas to trouble shoot? I am following the exact guide here => https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Tried to use ssh-keygen -R github.com, still not working,

```
$ ssh-keygen -R github.com
# Host github.com found: line 10 type RSA
/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts.old
$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is (skip fingerprint details here).
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: `ssh -vvvT git@github.com` check if it is really that key which you added to github, and is offered by your host.

Comment: @Jakuje, the command is super helpful, I find the reason is in .ssh/config, there is an IdentifyFile setup to be my company ssh key (which I need to use at work), but now I need to access some public open source project on github, I want to use another ssh key. Wondering if it is possible to set two ssh keys, one for work and one for open source project access to github? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up multiple github identities. It is described even in [on several places](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996).

Basic idea is to create two aliases in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work

Host github.com-the-other
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_the-other
```

and then change the `url` in your `.git/config` from `github.com to`github.com-the-other`. Than the line will look like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com-the-other:the-other/gfs.git
```

Comment: Thanks Jakuje, a bit lost, is the first entry for work or for github open source project? And why I need to specify `User git`?

Comment: The first is probably the one you already have there (maybe slightly modified), the second is for your (new) opensource project. You don't need to specify the user, because it is already in the `url` of your repository, but it avoids another confusion if you would ever use some repository without user in the `url`.

Comment: Thanks Jakuje, what is the security risk if I use the same key for both work and github open source project?

Comment: BTW, Jakuje, for your comments, "change the url in your .git/config", do you mean change the url in `.ssh/config`?

Comment: nope. The `git` config of already cloned repository. Or just clone with this modified `url` in `git clone` command. If company doesn't prevent you from using the same key for other activity, there should be no security risk to use it also for github.

Comment: Thanks Jakuje, I tried to use command `git clone git@github.com:tensorflow/tensorflow.git` after changing .ssh/config to add a new ssh key as IdentityFile for Host github.com, it works for me without changing .git/config, want to confirm with you it is the right solution? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It is fine. Originally I understood that you use already different key for different github account. If not it is way easier (just specify the key in config).